# At Scada-LTS installation I get error while running docker-compose up

Tags: raspberry-pi, scadalts

I have a Raspberry Pi4 at first with Raspbian OS downloaded directly from Pi Imager, and now a Debian 11 armhf downloaded directly from debian webpage.

uname -a =>
Linux "hostname" 5.15.84-v7l+ #1613 SMP Thu Jan 5 12:01:26 GMT 2023 armv7l GN U/Linux

I am in the process of installing Scada-LTS according to these Quick Start instructions: https://github.com/SCADA-LTS/Scada-LTS/wiki/#mysql

And with both OS's I get the following error while running: docker-compose up =>

Starting mysql ... done
Starting docker_scadalts_1 ... done
Attaching to mysql, docker_scadalts_1
scadalts_1  | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
mysql       | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
mysql exited with code 1
docker_scadalts_1 exited with code 1

As I get errors, I ran: docker-compose up database =>

Starting mysql ... done
Attaching to mysql
mysql       | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
mysql exited with code 1

Which is the same error, so I assume it is not a problem of starting one docker before the other...

Any additional information you might need, just let me know.

Hope you guys can help me get Scada-LTS running on Raspberry Pi.

Thank you.